# Random errors while doing Enter-PSSession in powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-remoting

I have setup lots of Powershell scripts on my WIndows 2008 R2 server. The scripts do lots of processing (data crunching, executing SQLCMD.exe, bcp.exe etc). All of these scripts work without issues.

I am trying to call and execute the scripts from a remote laptop (within the same network) using the following command:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName sun -ConfigurationName myprofile
```

The "myprofile" currently has just one function that will change directory to c:

This allows me to execute the scripts from my local laptop, however, they "run" on the server. That is my understanding.

However, I have not seen any scripts execute fully. At random intervals, the scripts fail with the below error messages... Once again, I have never seen these errors when I am trying to run the scripts on the server itself.

Any inputs on how to "fix" these errors? Any settings that I need to do on the "client" in terms of memory allocation?

a.

```
Processing data for a remote command failed with the following error message: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

b.

```
Get-Content : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
At E:\automation\mssql-upload.ps1:144 char:14
+     (get-content <<<<  $PipeFile -ReadCount 1000) | set-content $FinalFile
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-Content], OutOfMemoryException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderContentReadError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

c.

```
[Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV
```

d.

```
Processing data for a remote command failed with the following error message: The WSMan provider host process did not return a proper response.  A provider in the host process may have behaved improperly. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

Comment: How much memory does the remote computer have configured per remote session?  Check with this command run on remote computer `Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB`.  If the value seems small you can change it with `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB <number> -Force`

Comment: I seem to be getting an error: `Get-Item : Cannot find path 'WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB' because it does not exist.`

Comment: if it helps: `Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
`

Comment: Figured out. need to run that as an administrator. Its set at 150 MB. What should be a recommended value?

Comment: Let me try that out and see if it helps...

Comment: So far, I have not seen any issues with 1024 MB. Can some one explain me what does this do? Does it reserve 1024 MB per remote session?

Comment: @DataRiver It prevents any one remote PowerShell session from bringing down the system because it consumes too much memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely your remote session is bumping up against the WS-Man quota `MaxMemoryPerShellMB`.  You can see the current value by executing this command on the remote machine:

```
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB
```

You can set a new value like so:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 512 -Force
```

This sets the value at 512MB.  Set it to a value that works for your application.

Comment: how big can you go, I have currently set this to 3096 and still get this error